# SwiftUI - properties not updating from ParentViewModel and ChildViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and I have the following protocols and viewModels in my project. Can someone please help me how to update the properties from my parentViewModel to childViewModel to SwiftUI View and why the delegate is not getting called? Thank you in advance!

```
public protocol ViewModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
  var isRegistered: Bool { get set }
  var shouldShowBanner: Bool { get set }
  var toggleValue: Bool { get set }
}

public protocol ChildViewModelDelegate: AnyObject {
   func switchValueChanged(isOn: Bool)
}

public class ChildViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
  @Published public var isRegistered: Bool = false
  @Published public var shouldShowBanner: Bool = false
  @Published public var toggleValue: Bool = false {
    didSet {
      delegate?.switchValueChanged(isOn: toggleValue)
    }
  }
  weak var delegate: ChildViewModelDelegate?
  public init(isRegistered: Bool = false, shouldShowBanner: Bool = false) {
    self.isRegistered = isRegistered
    self.shouldShowBanner = shouldShowBanner
  }
}
```

/// I cannot make this class public, due to other internal variables that are restricted for exposure.

```
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject, ChildViewModelDelegate {
  @Published childViewModel: ChildViewModel = ChildViewModel()

  init(childViewModel: ChildViewModel, isRegistered: Bool) {
    self.childViewModel = childViewModel
    self.childViewModel.delegate = self
    self.childViewModel.isRegistered = isRegistered
    self.childViewModel.shouldShowBanner = false
  }

  func switchValueChanged(isOn: Bool) {
    /// Getting the value of isRegistered from a network call and I want to assign it to child view model to update the UI
    self.childViewModel.isRegistered = isRegistered
    self.childViewModel.shouldShowBanner = isRegistered
  }
}
```

/// Now comes my SwiftUI view which actually uses the ChildViewModel (because I cannot expose ParentViewModel).

```
struct MySwiftUIView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChildViewModel
 init(viewModel: ChildViewModel) {
   self.viewModel = viewModel
 }
 var body: some View {
   Vstack {
     if viewModel.shouldShowBanner {
       /// Show banner component
     }
     Toggle("Title", isOn: $viewModel.isToggleSwitchON)
       .onChange(of: viewModel.isToggleSwitchON) { value in
          /// This is not calling the delegate func switchValueChanged(isOn: Bool) which is in the parent viewModel
          viewModel.toggleValue = value
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your are using multiple instances of `ChildViewModel`.

Comment: To use SwiftUI effectively you have to forget View model objects and learn the View struct